# How to overwrite != operator?

Tags: c#

I try to ovewrite != operator:

```
public class Box
{
    public Box()
    {
    }

    public Box(double height, double width)
    {
        Height = height;
        Width = width;
    }

    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (Height.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ Width.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        return obj.GetType() == GetType() && Equals((Box)obj);
    }

    protected bool Equals(Box other)
    {
        return Math.Abs(Height - other.Height) + Math.Abs(Width - other.Width) < 0.001;
    }
    public static bool operator ==(Box left, Box right)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, left))
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(null, right))
            return false;

        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Box left, Box right)
    {
        var t = !(left == right);
        return t;
    }
}

public class BetterBox:Box{

}
```

And try to use != operator

```
var box = new Box();
var betterBox = box as BetterBox;
if(betterBox!=null){
    --do-something
}
```

In this case != return `true` and code enter into `if`. 
Whats wrong here? Why it's heppens?
On mdsn i see same code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/336aedhh%28v%3dvs.100%29

Comment: It is the same as calling `if (!(box == null))`, and your `==` operator if either side reference-equals `null`, it returns false, which becomes `if (!(false))` which is `if (true)`...

Comment: @RonBeyer yeah `!=` retuns `true`. But i seen simular code on mdsn and stackoverflow. I miss something?

Comment: @KliverMax - You *probably* missed the very first check that should usually be in every check for equality: `if (ReferenceEquals(left, right)) { return true; }`

Comment: @KliverMax You may have missed that the example you linked to on MS docs is for a value type, not a reference type so the rules are a little different. What Corak says is true for reference types, you need that check and it should be the first one for reference types.

Comment: @Corak `return ReferenceEquals(left, right);`

Comment: Also, in newer versions, you might want to use `if(thing is null)` and `if (!(thing is null))` respectively.

Comment: @Corak I skiped this check becouse i don't sure that understand what this do. But will try it right now.

Comment: @LewsTherin - Not necessarily. Two instances could be considered equal even if they're not reference-equal. Consider: `class X { public int Y { get;set; } }` and `var a = new X { Y = 1 }; var b = new X { Y = 1 };` - now `a` and `b` would not be reference-equal, but are probably intended to be seen as equal.

Comment: @Corak I think you were responding to someone else on accident. All I did was refactor your `if (ReferenceEquals(left, right)) { return true; }` code, to `return ReferenceEquals(left, right);`. These statements do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @KliverMax - It does, what it says. It returns `true` if two variables reference the exact same thing (basically: point to the same address in memory). So if `betterBox` is a NullReference and `null` is a NullReference, then they are reference-equal and `betterBox == null` would return `true` and consequently `betterBox != null` would return `false`.

Comment: @LewsTherin - nope. I tried to explain, that your refactor would go too far. I said that check should be the very **first** check. But it should by no means be the **only** check. -- in my example, I'd expect `operator ==` to look something like `{ if (ReferenceEquals(left, right)) { return true; } if (ReferenceEquals(null, left) || ReferenceEquals(null, right)) { return false; } return left.Y == right.Y; }`

Comment: @Corak This check helps me. How about case when i have a 2 boxes with same `width` and `height`? `ReferenceEquals(left,right)` will return false?

Comment: @KliverMax - exactly! That's why *additional* checks are needed.

Comment: @Corak I'm an idiot, disregard my comments.

Comment: To check for types use the `is` operator instead of `GetType()`. The first is compile time and the later runtime.  Use `if(obj is Box box) { return Equals(box); }` (requires .NET 4.7.1 I think).

Comment: This box should be implemented as an immutable struct. The current design will be horrible to use. And your Equals() isn't transitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the full implementation of `Box` using equality checks (implementing `IEquatable<Box>`). Below are the test results:

```
       a        b     a==b     a!=b    a.Equals(b)    b.Equals(a)
    null     null     True    False                              
 [30×10]     null    False     True          False               
 [30×10]  [30×10]     True    False           True           True
    null  [30×10]    False     True                         False
```

I have implemented `Equals(Box)`, `Equals(object)`, `GetHashCode()`, `operator ==`, `operator !=` and `ToString()`.

```
public class Box : IEquatable<Box>
{
    // Place values in constants
    public const double SizeTolerance = 0.001;

    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }

    public static bool operator ==(Box left, Box right)
    {
        if(!ReferenceEquals(left, null))
        {
            // consider that left.Equals(null) should return false
            return left.Equals(right);
        }
        return ReferenceEquals(left, right);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Box left, Box right)
    {
        return !(left==right);
    }

    #region IEquatable Members
    /// <summary>
    /// Equality overrides from <see cref="System.Object"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The object to compare this with</param>
    /// <returns>False if object is a different type, otherwise it calls <code>Equals(Box)</code></returns>
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(obj is Box other)
        {
            return Equals(other);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks for equality among <see cref="Box"/> classes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">The other <see cref="Box"/> to compare it to</param>
    /// <returns>True if equal</returns>
    public bool Equals(Box other)
    {
        if(ReferenceEquals(other, null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return Math.Abs(Width-other.Width)<SizeTolerance
            && Math.Abs(Height-other.Height)<SizeTolerance;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the hash code for the <see cref="Box"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The int hash value</returns>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hc = 17;
            hc = 23*hc + Width.GetHashCode();
            hc = 23*hc + Height.GetHashCode();
            return hc;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"[{Width}×{Height}]";
    }
}
```

and the code to test it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{"a",8} {"b",8} {"a==b",8} {"a!=b",8} {"a.Equals(b)",14} {"b.Equals(a)",14}");
        Box a = null;
        Box b = null;
        Debug.WriteLine($"{a?.ToString()??"null",8} {b?.ToString()??"null",8} {a==b,8} {a!=b,8} {a?.Equals(b),14} {b?.Equals(a),14}");
        a = new Box() { Height = 10, Width = 30 };
        Debug.WriteLine($"{a?.ToString()??"null",8} {b?.ToString()??"null",8} {a==b,8} {a!=b,8} {a?.Equals(b),14} {b?.Equals(a),14}");
        b = new Box() { Height = 10, Width = 30 };
        Debug.WriteLine($"{a?.ToString()??"null",8} {b?.ToString()??"null",8} {a==b,8} {a!=b,8} {a?.Equals(b),14} {b?.Equals(a),14}");
        a = null;
        Debug.WriteLine($"{a?.ToString()??"null",8} {b?.ToString()??"null",8} {a==b,8} {a!=b,8} {a?.Equals(b),14} {b?.Equals(a),14}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of `==` operator is wrong. You need to consider both operands when checking for null. Currently, you are returning false if `left` is null, ignoring the value of `right` operand. If both of them are `null` it should return true.

```
public static bool operator ==(Box left, Box right)
{
    var isLeftNull = ReferenceEquals(null, left);
    var isRightNull = ReferenceEquals(null, right);

    if (isLeftNull && isRightNull)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (isLeftNull || isRightNull)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return left.Equals(right);
}
```

Comment: It's right that this additional checks same with @Corac commentary `if (ReferenceEquals(left, right)) { return true; }`?

Comment: @KliverMax it is not enough, you should make sure none of the operands is null before calling equals.

Comment: If `right` is `null` then `left.Equals(right)` should return false (always).

Comment: @ja72 - indeed, but this implies that `left` **must not** be null (if it was, calling `left.Equals` would throw a NullReferenceException).

Comment: @KliverMax - yes, they're logically equivalent. -- again, my suggestion was just to put `if (ReferenceEquals(left, right)) { return true; }` *before* your other already existing checks.